# performSegueWithIdentifier not showing view controller as expected

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have programatically created a button called 'menu' which was changed to a UIBarButtonItem called 'menuButton'. When the button is clicked I want to call a segue using the performSegueWithIdentifier.

Universal.swift

```
struct UniversalStatic {
    static let data = Universal()
}

public class Universal {
    let menuButton : UIBarButtonItem
    let menu : UIButton

init(){
    menu =  UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    menu.setImage(UIImage(named: "menu.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    menu.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 20)
    menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menu)
}
```

HomeViewController.swift

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    func goToMenuVC() {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("test", sender: self)
    }

    override func performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) {
        print("called")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UniversalStatic.data.menu.addTarget(self, action: "goToMenuVC", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UniversalStatic.data.menuButton
    }

func viewDidAppear() {
    UniversalStatic.data.menu.addTarget(self, action: "goToMenuVC", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UniversalStatic.data.menuButton
}
```

The print statement is printed so i know the 'performSegueWithIdentifier' is been called however the show segue is bene actioned.

I have attached a screenshot of the segue identifier.
[image]

Comment: try to remove overridden performSegueWithIdentifier method

Comment: @azimov I get the error: "Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword"

Comment: Remove the whole method, not just the word "override"

Comment: Another option would be to call super's implementation

Comment: @azimov @ dan Thanks that worked! Something odd is happening now though. 

When i click the menuButton it takes me to the HomeViewController (expected). However when i then go back to the menuViewController and click the menuButton its seems to load the HomeViewController twice.

Its like a loop as when i do it again it seems to load it 3 times etc...

Comment: Remove from viewDidAppear method those 2 statements.

Comment: @azimov Just tried that and the same thing is occuring

Comment: Ok, so try to call UniversalStatic.data.menu.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: .AllEvents) each time you call UniversalStatic.data.menu.addTarget ...  . P.S Try to rethink your solution

Comment: How are you moving from the menu to the HomeViewController? You may be adding a segue to something that's already being done by the NavigationController. I believe the correct way is to unwind back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add:

```
super.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier, sender: sender)
```

In your `performSegueWithIdentifier` method.

Comment: thanks that calls the view as expected. The loop mentions in the above still occurs though. Any ideas?

Comment: I think that the problem is in this line of the viewDidAppear method: UniversalStatic.data.menu.addTarget(self, action: "goToMenuVC", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside). Everytime the view appears (even when you go back from the menu) you add the view controller as a target of the button. You should check if self is already a target before adding it.